# How to keep a user logged in?

Tags: html, jsp, tomcat, authentication

I'm trying to keep a user logged in after they have entered their details on the login screen. I'm using apache tomcat and MS access database. I can log in with a user stored in my database. But I can't figure out how to keep the user logged in throughout my website. I have been reading up about sessions and trying sample code but I can't get it to work, I keep getting different errors. I managed to "Welcome" the user by name after login, but I can't keep the welcome user message, if I click on any other of my webpages.

### loginJsp.jsp-

```
<sql:setDataSource
var = "bookdB"
scope = "session"
driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"
url = "jdbc:odbc:bookdB"
/>

<sql:query var ="NameCheck" scope = "session" dataSource = "${bookdB}">

SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE Username = ?
AND Password = ?

<sql:param value = "${param.user}" />
<sql:param value = "${param.password}" />
</sql:query>

<c:if test = "${NameCheck.rowCount == 0}">
<jsp:forward page = "loginError.html"/>
</c:if>

<c:if test = "${NameCheck.rowCount != 0}">
<jsp:forward page = "index.jsp"/>
```

index.jsp

```
 <sql:query dataSource="${bookdB}" var="result">
SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE Username = ?
AND Password = ?

<sql:param value = "${param.user}" />
<sql:param value = "${param.password}" />
 </sql:query>

<font color="orange" face="Futura Std-Light" size="4">         
 <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}"> 
   Welcome ${row.FirstName}!
 </c:forEach>  
</font>
```

---

[image]

---

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks!

Is this right:

```
<c:if test = "${NameCheck.rowCount == 0}">
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("connecte", "true");
    session.setAttribute("login", "${param.user}");
<jsp:forward page = "loginError.html"/>
</c:if>
```

Comment: well as this is a simple assignment I would say put the user/flag or something in a session. And always check the value for each page if user is loged on. Or maybe have a header.jsp that is included in all pages. However a Session timeout or logout.jsp could invalidate the session. If session value is invalid then redirect to login.jsp. In real life I would do this using java ee declartive security, but this is overkill for your assignment.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll try that. btw its not an assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your servlet action handler add this:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("connecte", "true");
session.setAttribute("login", "TOM");
```

in your JSP add this on the top of your page

```
<%
if (session.getAttribute("connecte") == null
        || !((String) session.getAttribute("connecte"))
                .equals("true")) {
    String redirectURL = "/path/ToYour/login.jsp;
    response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
}
%>
<h1>Hello <%= session.getAttribute("login") %></h1>
```

if it's OK it will show 
Hello Tom

#

login.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="US-ASCII">
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="LoginServlet" method="post">

Username: <input type="text" name="user">
<br>
Password: <input type="password" name="pwd">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

#

LoginServlet.java:

```
package com.journaldev.servlet.session;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final String userID = "Pankaj";
private final String password = "journaldev";

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // get request parameters for userID and password
    String user = request.getParameter("user");
    String pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");

    if(userID.equals(user) && password.equals(pwd)){
        Cookie loginCookie = new Cookie("user",user);
        //setting cookie to expiry in 30 mins
        loginCookie.setMaxAge(30*60);
        response.addCookie(loginCookie);
        response.sendRedirect("LoginSuccess.jsp");
    }else{
        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.html");
        PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
        out.println("<font color=red>Either user name or password is wrong.</font>");
        rd.include(request, response);
    }

}

}
```

#

LoginSuccess.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"                             "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Login Success Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
String userName = null;
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
if(cookies !=null){
for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
if(cookie.getName().equals("user")) userName = cookie.getValue();
}
}
if(userName == null) response.sendRedirect("login.html");
%>
<h3>Hi <%=userName %>, Login successful.</h3>
<br>
<form action="LogoutServlet" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Logout" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @anosi anosi for the reply. Their are more users then just Tom. So if logged in a Joe or someone else. I would want the message to say welcome Joe.

Comment: it's just an example ;) with session you can use any kind of object
    session.setAttribute("login", ObjectLogin);

Comment: when you try to retrieve an object from your variable session don't forget to cast it ;)

Comment: @anosi anosi I added the path to my login page. But everytime i enter the login details now, its just opens the login screen again.

Comment: in your action/servlet did you set the session: session.setAttribute("connecte", "true");
session.setAttribute("login", "TOM");

Comment: use only this test if (session.getAttribute("connecte") == null) {
    String redirectURL = "/path/ToYour/login.jsp;
    response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
}

Comment: in your loginJsp.jsp put only the form.
in the servlet put action handler:
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("connecte", "true");
session.setAttribute("login", "TOM");

in your index:

<%
if (session.getAttribute("connecte") == null
        || !((String) session.getAttribute("connecte"))
                .equals("true")) {
    String redirectURL = "/path/ToYour/login.jsp;
    response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
}
%>
<h1>Hello <%= session.getAttribute("login") %></h1>

Comment: I've went through that tutorial already. The trouble seems to be with HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("connecte", "true");
session.setAttribute("login", "TOM");. When i took away the if statement (if (session.getAttribute("connecte") == null) to stop it redirecting, it came up hello null.  its not retrieving the name right.

Comment: my form is in **login.html**, i've added to **loginJsp.jsp**. the follwing: <c:if test = "${NameCheck.rowCount == 0}">
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("connecte", "true");
    session.setAttribute("login", "${param.user}");
<jsp:forward page = "loginError.html"/>
</c:if>       and **login.jsp** has the other if statment u posted.

Comment: Thanks @Anas ZAHOURI for the help. Much appreciated.